# How to go to new line in a text document using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Using

```
File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", "This is the first line")
File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", "This is the second line")
```

How do I make the second line of text appear under the first one, as if I hit the Enter key?  Doing it this way simply puts the second line right next to the first line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `Environment.NewLine`

```
File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", "This is the first line")
File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", Environment.NewLine + "This is the second line")
```

Or you can use the `StreamWriter`

```
Using writer As new StreamWriter("mytextfile.text", true)
    writer.WriteLine("This is the first line")
    writer.WriteLine("This is the second line")
End Using
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have many of this calls It's way better to use a StringBuilder:

```
Dim sb as StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
sb.AppendLine("This is the first line")
sb.AppendLine("This is the second line")
sb.AppendLine("This is the third line")
....
' Just one call to IO subsystem
File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", sb.ToString())
```

If you have really many many strings to write then you could wrap everything in a method.

```
Private Sub AddTextLine(ByVal sb As StringBuilder, ByVal line as String)
    sb.AppendLine(line)
    If sb.Length > 100000 then
        File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", sb.ToString()) 
        sb.Length = 0
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: That means working with the complete string in memory, depending on the size, that can be a problem.

Comment: @Magnus yes but could easily handled with some intermediate calls to AppendAllText. See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", "This is the first line")
File.AppendAllText("c:\mytextfile.text", vbCrLf & "This is the second line")
```

[`vbCrLf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf.aspx) is a constant for a newline.