# Put text in textarea in specific way

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im using VS and created html page with textarea, I need to put the text in two rows from the start one above one like

```
row1:mytext
row2:mytext2
```

in order to make it work I should put it exactly like following and If I doing formatting to the page the text was removed from where I want it to be, there is a way to put the text in specific position in text area?

```
<div>
    <textarea rows="2" cols="700" disabled="disabled" class="path-width">Expire: @ViewBag.CertExpireDate 
    Subject: @ViewBag.Cert</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to put \n between the two lines: row1:mytext\n row2:mytext2
Check out this thread too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095155/how-to-go-to-new-line-in-a-text-document-using-vb-net

Comment: It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Rpu3N/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&#10;` ancii code between line. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SFL7K/)

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="700" disabled="disabled">
     Expire: @ViewBag.CertExpireDate &#10; Subject: @ViewBag.Cert
</textarea>
```

**UPDATED**

You can remove whitespaces using jquery [trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w5n2p/)

```
var text = $('textarea').val().trim();
$('textarea').html(text);
```

Comment: Thanks  now I've it in two sperate lines but it looks like but for the first text 
there is spaceses before how should I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="700" disabled="disabled" class="path-width">Expire: @ViewBag.CertExpireDate@(Environment.NewLine)Subject: @ViewBag.Cert</textarea>
```

`@(Environment.NewLine)` will add new line and it will bot be removed when you do the formatting.

Comment: @Mark: OP wants to display the `Expire: @ViewBag.CertExpireDate` and `Subject: @ViewBag.Cert` as two separate rows. OP's issue is if the page is formatted (may be using Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document) `textarea` tag may become one line and he will lose the `NewLine`.

Comment: your explanation in the comment is ok, but the explanation in your answer is still very brief. You might want to put your entire comment into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
         <textarea rows="2" cols="700" disabled="disabled" class="path-width">
 Expire: @ViewBag.CertExpireDate
 Subject: @ViewBag.Cert                                
            </textarea>
```

Maybe the css class

```
class="path-width"
```

causes this problem. Check http://jsfiddle.net/7SqHc/

Comment: You need to add the explanation to your answer, not in a comment. The explanation you just gave is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks but I dont want it like this I want it to be line under line ...(since the format issue),in your example you take the first row text and put it near the closing tag of the text area which looks like exactly what I did...I want it to be line under line

Comment: @HolgerTans do you mean that?? otherwise add the result view and the css class

Comment: Thanks but not you just move it to the left but if I do formating to the page I still have the problem...

Comment: @HolgerTans expose plz the css class `path-width` or try to remove  `class="path-width"`

Comment: Thanks I remove the class but nothing was changed...I voted up for your effort