# How to add a Return Function

Tags: vb.net, return

I am currently writing to a .txt file i would like to know how to add a 'return' function so when writing to the text file for it doesnt do this:

Testtesttesttesttesttest

But instead

Test

Test

Test

This is my current code (whilst i understand its basic its working so far)

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\test.txt",
    TextBox1.Text, True)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\test.txt",
    "   ", True)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\test.txt",
    TextBox2.Text, True)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\test.txt",
    "   ", True)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("F:\Documents\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExtentionLocator\ExtentionLocator\test.txt",
    TextBox3.Text, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to append a "new line" character. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095155/how-to-go-to-new-line-in-a-text-document-using-vb-net

Comment: Perfect done it! Thanks for your help :) if you add that as an answer i will be happy to confirm it, have a great weekend - Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to specify a line break is with `Environment.NewLine`:

```
TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine
```

There are lots of ways to specify carriage returns and line feeds but the most correct way to specify a line break is with `Envirnment.NewLine`.  It will return the a `String` containing the appropriate characters for the current system, which will be a carriage return and line feed pair on Windows (CR-LF, \r\n in C-based languages, ASCII 13 and 10) and a line feed alone on non-Windows systems.